# how can I show only the new rows in the datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

how can I show only the rows in the gridview,
where primarykey>= primarykey.max - 20     (the 20 latest lines)

When I create a SQL Statement,
can I use a variable which is declared at vb.net?(for example a counter which counts the amount of added rows)
where must I put that statement in?

Comment: how are you populating the datagridview? are you doing it from data source or from data table?

Comment: Provide what you have done so far.

Comment: @Vladimir olesky with a datasource

Comment: @kostas ch. I know it´s common to put some code in the question. My problem is that I am in the sixth week of programming this project, and I dont believe it´s much useful to put my whole code in here. 

I guess I need to change the sql Statement in the proberties of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this SQL statement as DataSource

```
SELECT TOP 20 FROM YourTable ORDER BY PrimaryKey DESC
```

**UPDATE**

If table name and PKEY must be dynamic you can use a parameterized command. Once the sql statement is formed you can fill a `DataSet` and use it as data source when populating the `DataGridView`

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 20 FROM ? ORDER BY ? DESC", Connection)            

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Table", YourDinamicTableName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PKey", YourDinamicKeyName)

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Adapter.Fill(ds)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Hello equisde, thx for your answer. the Probem is that the "20" should be a variable which can change. that means I need a parameterized query. and with that the problem is that I use a datasource and I have absolutely no knowledge about the datasetDesignercode which is created automatically.

Comment: thx for the update Looks good.
No the table name doesnt need to be dynamic, only pkey, but to correct that is easy. 

how does the "?" work. is the first ? linked to the first cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, and the second ? linked with the second cmd.Parameters.AddWtihValue ?

Comment: Yes. Parameters are being added in the same order that they occurs